# How to use FlagsAttribute

Tags: c#, enums

A developer on my project has implemented the following enum

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions
{
    Overview = 1,
    Detail = 3,
    Edit = 7,
    Delete = 31,
    Block = 39, // Requires Edit = 7, and It's own location = 32. Therefore 7 + 32 = 39.
    Unblock =  71, // Requires Edit = 7, and It's own location = 64. Therefore 7 + 64 = 71.
    All = int.MaxValue
}
```

Now, as you can see he has, for example, made `Details = 3`.  The reason he has done this is that Details (which should have been 2) includes overview as well (2+1=3).

I always thought that the way to do these things is to use powers of 2 in the enum and do any oring and anding outside of the enum.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with defining combinations in the enum in order to make life easier for users of the enum.   That said, it is probably a short-sighted decision (inflexible and hard to understand code) decision to leave out that various power-of-2 options that make up the combinations.

Comment: also, if one would like to remove e.g. Detail flag (permission &= ~Permissions.Detail) he would remove Overwiew as well

Answer (score 5):

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) recomends to define flagged enum constants in powers of two but there is no restriction to define flagged enum constants with any possible values.

> Define enumeration constants in powers of two, that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap.